# Select cell in worksheet_open, ONLY the first time it is activated

Tags: excel, vba

I was looking for a script that selects a cell like `("A5")` to reset the view of the sheet, but only the first time the sheet is activated.

I have a basic Worksheet_Activate, but this resets me every time I move between sheets and back.

Thanks in advance!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Range("A5").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: You could set a global variable, e.g., `const checkFlag`, and do a check for `if checkFlag <> 1 then // range().select // checkFlag = 1 // End if`

Comment: Please, define what **first time** should be. Only once for all the workbook life? One time after opening the workbook? One time per day, or what? Basically, your event code should place in Registry a marker, eloquent according to that **first time** definition...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean, "In a multisheet workbook, whenever I select/activate a certain sheet, I want to control (reset) the view of that sheet by selecting a certain cell, but I only want that to happen the first time I select/activate that sheet, during the time the workbook is open."

Public variables persist while the workbook is open, maybe this:

```
Public isInitialized As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    If Not isInitialized Then
        'put your first time only code here, ie Range("A5").Select
        isInitialized = True
    End If
End Sub
```

The Public variable will be false until the first time the designated sheet activates, then will persist True while the workbook is open.

Note that the Worksheet_Activate event doesn't fire between open workbooks, in that case, use the Workbook_Activate event in ThisWorkbook.